# Remover un dato en una lista de listas JSON

Tags: c#, json

Quiero meterme en una lista que está dentro de otra lista para borrar una lista según un dato que esté dentro de la lista que quiero eliminar, estos son los datos

```
{
  "Empresas": [
    {
      "NombreEmpresa": "TEST1"
      "Empleados": [
        {
          "Nombre": "Matias Vargas",
          "FechaNacimiento": ""
        },
        {
          "Nombre": "Luis Pérez",
          "FechaNacimiento": ""
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "NombreEmpresa": "TEST2",
      "Empleados": [
        {
          "Nombre": "Martin Sanchez",
          "FechaNacimiento": "",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Como ven quiero meterme dentro de "Empresas" para después meterme dentro de los empleados de la empresa que se llame "TEST1" y borrar a Luis Pérez (Su nombre y fecha de nacimiento)

Esto es lo que quería hacer:

```
string readed = File.ReadAllText("empresas.json");
var jObject = JObject.Parse(readed);
JArray EmpleadosArray = (JArray)jObject["Empleados"].Where(obj => obj["NombreEmpresa"].Value<string>() == "TEST1");
var empleadoParaEliminar = EmpleadosArray.Where(obj => obj["Empleados"].Where(obj2 => obj2["Nombre"].Value<string>() == "Luis Pérez")));
                
foreach (var item in empleadoParaEliminar)
{
       EmpleadosArray.Remove(item);
}
```

Pero por obvias razones me dió 2 errores

> No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>'
> en 'bool'

> No se puede convertir expresión lambda en el tipo delegado indicado
> porque algunos de los tipos de valores devueltos del bloque no se
> pueden convertir implícitamente en el tipo de valor devuelto del
> delegado

No necesito hacerlo así exactamente, si existe otra forma de acceder a los datos agradecería bastante que me la pasaran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demoré algunos meses pero por fin encontré la respuesta aunque la solución no era lo que quería exactamente aunque tal vez fue mejor, lo que hice fue agregar una cadena a los Empleados de nombre "ID" para identificar de mejor manera al Empleado

```
public class Empleado
{
       public string ID { get; set; } 
}
```

Y ahora para buscar la ID hice lo siguiente

```
        string readed = File.ReadAllText(data);
        var jToken = JToken.Parse(readed);
        var resultado = jToken["Empresas"].SelectMany(x => x["Empleados"]).ToList(); // Busca a TODOS los Empleados

        foreach (var item in resultado) 
        {
            var times = item.SelectTokens("ID").Values(); // Busca el ID en TODOS los empleados
            if (times.Where(x => x.ToString().Trim() == text).Any()) // Si la ID es igual a text, entonces seleccionará solo al Empleado con esa ID y descartará a los demás
            {
                item.Remove(); // Remueve al Empleado seleccionado
            }
        }
```